# Repeat some operation in the same column

Tags: excel

I'm new to excel. I want to subtract All element of A from I1 and then divide it by J1. So, I use =(A1-l1)/j1 and then paste the same operation for other element but it doesn't work and the operation convert to  =(A2-l2)/j2 and  =(A3-l3)/j3 ...but I want  =(A2-l1)/j1 and  =(A3-l1)/j1 what should I do?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
=(A1-I1)/J1
```

Use

```
=(A1-I$1)/J$1
```

a `$` before a row number ensures it will not change, and you can also put $ before a column letter, such as the case with `=$A1` or even `=$A$1` to freeze both.

In windows pressing `F4` in the formula editor will do this for you. It will cycle thru putting a $ before letter and number, and then both, and then neither. if no values in the formula are highlighted, it will affect the value the cursor is on. otherwise, it will affect any and all highlighted range values. its called absolute reference.

Comment: what returns 0? one of the cells? the first cell? all of them? what formula are you using exactly, and what column is it in?

Comment: also please see my addendum in the answer about the behavior of F4, in case that is what you used. note that in your case you want `L$1` and `J$1`, not `$L1` or `$J1`

Comment: I use your answer =(A1-L$1)/J$1 exactly and return 0.

Comment: sorry, typo! That needs to be `I$1` instead of `L$1`. My mistake.

Comment: Thanks :-). I also didn't see.